# Add woocommerce plugin in own theme

Tags: css, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have created a customize theme in wordpress and now i want to add woocommerce plugin in my theme. I installed woocommerce plugin and active it. So how would I integrate that plugin with my own theme i.e. when I would add product, it should be show to my theme's home page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the templates folder inside the Woocommerce plug-in folder and place them in a custom Woocommerce folder inside your theme folder.

every changes you make inside the custom Woocommerce folder will override the core files of the Woocommerce plug-in without loosing them after an update.

You have to give us more information aboutdisplaying products on your home page because there are some ways to do that.

**Like:**

you can edit your homepage template with some Woocommerce functions, to get the result or maybe you have an 3rd party theme with some Woocommerce intergration.

Comment: Actually I had html,css and js only and I convert those fles into wordpress theme. So i tried a lot but woocommerce pulgin working not fine with my custom css, infact I downloaded a free wordpress theme and add woocommerce plugin to that free theme and it works fine.